# Best way to test connection quality between client and server

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

The client has a bunch of ip addresses of web servers. My task is to check connection quality between client and each of these servers  and choose which one has the lowest latency.

The first idea which came into my head was to establish tcp connection using `java.net.Socket` class and measure time took to do that. But I am not sure that it's the best way to solve this task.

So, my questions are:

1) Is using `java.net.Socket` a proper solution?

2) If the answer is positive, should I do only one connection or 2-3 and get the average time?

3) If the answer is negative, what is the proper way to do it from Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I'd say using `java.net.Socket` would be overshooting, perhaps it is better to use the `java.net.URLConnection` that can be obtained from the `java.net.URL` that you are going to use anyway.

3) You can create as many `URL` instances as servers you have, obtain the `URLConnection` from each of them via the `openConnection` method and then invoke its `connection` method measuring the time it takes.

This would not only measure pure network latency but also processing time in each of the servers, at the end of the day, you are downloading the whole content. In a way you are measuring also how loaded each of the server is at the moment. This might be important if the content is produced by some kind of application and not only a pure web server serving static pages.

If you do something like this I would recommend doing this process in a separate thread every now and then so that the main thread uses whatever server is deemed best at every moment.

If it is a matter of pure network latency, then using a plain socket would be a much better and simpler solution.

2) Yes, I think averaging 2-3 connections makes sense in the case of pure network latency but when using the `URLConnection` solution it would add too much load.

I hope it helps.